# One uploader and two different file types (pdf & xml) with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is it possible to use one Uploader for two different file types with CarrierWave?

I've seen Carrierwave has versioning for images, but the file types I'm interested are PDF and XML. I need to upload a PDF version of my object, as well as a XML version to Amazon S3.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

exactly like you have write in carrierwave documentation

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf xml)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of someway to map two files to one attribute. I guess I have to mount the uploader twice and use two attributes. Thanks.